# What weapon is the Stinger wielding?

Tags: weapons, dnd-3e

On page 81 in *Monsters of Faerûn*, [the Stinger is shown holding with both hands a two-pronged implement](https://web.archive.org/web/20161101195644/http://archive.wizards.com/dnd/images/mof_gallery/MonFaePG81.jpg) that doen't look like any polearm or weapon I recognize. The stats block only lists its natural attacks and a spiked chain weapon, so that doesn't help. What weapon is this?

[image: the stinger, a half-scorpion centaur type person holding a very complicated looking spear-hook thing]

Answer (score 11):

You have entered the dreaded zone of "the art order doesn't match the stat block," which is pretty common given the time-bound nature of book production.

It looked to me like a military fork, but given some more research it is probably intended to be a snazzed-up ranseur. No weapon or armor survives illustration in 3e without being made more EXTREME! and spiky.

[image]

Why a ranseur? Because that's actually the traditional weapon of the "manscorpion," a monster which has existed in D&D since Basic and was big in Greyhawk. [Canonfire! notes](http://www.canonfire.com/cf/modules.php?name=Forums&file=viewtopic&t=696&highlight=) that "the actual Manscorpion (aka Tlincali) was reprinted in Monsters of Faerun as the "Stinger"."

It's different from the very similar "scorpionfolk" in 3e, which were given lances instead, I think it's pretty clear this isn't a lance. Scorpionfolk are a remake of the "sandmasker" from the Sword & Sorcery Creature Collection and though similar, generally considered a different strain of monster than the manscorpion/tlincali/stinger.

Anyway, given the pretty good deduction that this is a republished manscorpion, and manscorpions use ranseurs, QED. They probably either reused art or sent out the old info with the art order before the developers were done switching to the more 3EXTREME!!! spiked chain.

Answer (score 3):

## It’s purely the artist’s imagination

There are no stats for this weapon, or alternatively it is any particular spear-or-polearm-like weapon the DM wants to call it. The artist was clearly not given any specific guidance on what weapon to draw the stinger wielding (since it’s clearly not a spiked chain!), and was given free reign to draw whatever he or she thought looked cool.

Were it me, and I *really* wanted my stats to match the picture, I would probably call it the mancatcher from *Complete Warrior*.